# How to efficiently export and import an Oracle table?

Tags: oracle

What is the best way to do this so that we waste the least time possible in both exporting and importing?

Taking into account that we are talking about a huge table with data from more than a decade.

What I've been planning so far:

```
directory=dumps
dumpfile=foo.dmp
parallel=8
logfile=foo_exp.log
tables=FOO
query=FOO:"WHERE TSP <= sysdate"
content=DATA_ONLY
```

The import part:

```
directory=dumps
dumpfile=foo.dmp
parallel=8
logfile=foo_imp.log
remap_table=FOO:FOO_REPARTITIONED
table_exists_action=REPLACE
```

Both scripts are going to be run like this:

```
nohup expdp USER/PWD@sid parfile=export.par &
nohup impdp USER/PWD@sid parfile=import.par &
```

Is the `parallel` parameter going to work as expected? Do I need to take anything else into account?

Comment: The proper setting for `PARALLEL` will depend on your available hardware and any other load on the system. I would advise experimenting with several values, as there is likely a point of diminishing return. Start with 2x the number of CPU cores available on a server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider some things

The `parallel` parameter from Datapump will not work unless you specify multiple dump files using the option `%U`. So in your case:

```
 directory=dumps
 dumpfile=foo_%U.dmp
 parallel=8
 logfile=foo_exp.log
 tables=FOO
 query=FOO:"WHERE TSP <= sysdate"
 content=DATA_ONLY
```

From the documentation

> The value that you specify for integer should be less than, or equal
> to, the number of files in the dump file set (or you should specify
> either the %U or %L substitution variables in the dump file
> specifications).

Also, take in consideration the following restrictions':

1. This parameter is valid only in the Enterprise Edition of Oracle
   Database 11g or later.
2. To export a table or table partition in parallel (using parallel
   query, or PQ, worker processes), you must have the
   DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role.
3. Transportable tablespace metadata cannot be exported in parallel.
4. Metadata cannot be exported in parallel when the NETWORK_LINK
   parameter is also used. The following objects cannot be exported in
   parallel: TRIGGER, VIEW OBJECT_GRANT, SEQUENCE, CONSTRAINT
   REF_CONSTRAINT.

So in your case set the parameter to a value adequate for the Hardware you have available in your server.

**Update**

Sorry for taking so much time to answer, but I was kind of busy. You were mentioning issues during the import. Well, if the structure of the tables is not the same ( for example, the partition key ) that might have an effect in the import operation. Normally in this case, I would suggest to be smart and speed up the import by splitting the operation in two steps:

**First Step - Import Datapump into normal table**

```
directory=dumps
dumpfile=foo_%U.dmp
parallel=8
logfile=foo_imp.log
remap_table=FOO:TMP_FOO
table_exists_action=TRUNCATE
TRANSFORM=DISABLE_ARCHIVE_LOGGING:Y
ACCESS_METHOD=DIRECT_PATH
content=DATA_ONLY
```

Be sure to have the table TMP_FOO created before starting the operation. The first step is to import the datapump file ( only data ) into a non partitoned table using direct path and without logging.

**Second Step - Direct Path Insert from TMP_FOO into your final table**

```
alter session enable parallel dml ;
alter session force parallel query;
insert /*+append parallel(a,8) */ into your_partitioned_table a 
select /*+parallel(b,8) */ * from tmp_foo b ;
commit;
```

I think this would make the time go down.

Comment: 1) Yes, we have EE 19c. 2) I've been able to test the export without errors in the logs although I don't have been granted that role, shouldn't there be a warning at least? 3) we don't want to export metadata, that's why I use DATA_ONLY, so it's ok. Btw, I had to change table_exists_action to TRUNCATE also (since REPLACE is not allowed in this case).

Comment: @anat0lius, I did not tell you anything about the  import, my bad. Indeed, as you are only exporting data, you can't use REPLACE, as you don't have the metadata. the most important part is to enable the parallel to write and read from multiple files using the %U parameter in the dump file. If you don't use it, you will see many workers, but they will be idle doing nothing

Comment: We tested also the import, and it took us 13h, for half of a year of data... While the export was just 6min. Any advice? Btw, looks like we don't need the roles you mentioned because the operations are local. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-8B6975D3-3BEC-4584-B416-280125EEC57E

Comment: can you tell me what import datapump you ran ? if the export was 6 minutes, there is something wrong in the import

Comment: The ones from my OP but using %U as you said. Parallel 8 (cpu x4). Basically we are taking a table that was partitioned by a x field and now we want to be partitioned by the time of insertion of the record.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez can it be because of the different partition structure?

Comment: Probably the different partition structure it is making the import much more complicated.

Comment: @anat0lius, I post an update. Let me know any doubts you might have

Comment: Thank you Robert. For the first step, the DIRECT_PATH is giving me an error of permissions (ORA-31696) so I removed it. I also removed table_exist_action so there is no need for me to create the table, is autogenerated in this case. In the end it took us 13min, which is very good. In the second step we are having issues with the TEMP tablespace, I had to extend it several times. Right now it's running, it's been 3h already, which is not so good. I'm thinking of creating a procedure to fill the table in smaller chunks and not choke the machine resources. I don't know, what do you think?

Comment: Update: in the end, step 2 took 13h. So there is no gain

Comment: @anat0lius., can you post the execution plan of the insert into the final table from the talbe imported by datapump ? do you have indexes in the partitioned table, don't you ? I am quite sure that this time is spent in the rebuild of the indexes, but to be sure I need to see the plan

Comment: Indeed, there are indexes. This is the table: https://pastebin.com/0iwcCQ7Q And here is the plan: https://i.ibb.co/yQ40WYN/Screenshot-at-2022-09-27-08-57-48.png